# Rowspan with apex repeat

Tags: visualforce, html, pageblocktable, repeat, table

I try to create a table with rowspan, but get a wrong table, could somebody help to resolve this?

This is my **UPD** VF Page:

```
 <apex:page controller="FinancialProductsController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" action="{!getData}">
 <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
     <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.BootstrapMincss)}"/>
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JQueryMinJs}"/>
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.BootstrapMinJs}"/>              
 </head>
 <apex:form id="Form">
     <apex:messages />              
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                 <tr class="headerRow">
                     <th>Business Division</th>
                     <th>Managed By</th>
                     <th>Product</th>
                     <th>Legal Entity</th>
                     <th>Launch Date</th>
                     <th>Sales Guru</th>
                     <th>PMO version (attachment)</th>
                     <th>Internal Presentation (attachment)</th>
                     <th>External Presentation(attachment)</th>
                 </tr>
                 <apex:repeat id="myRepeatHeader" value="{!divisionList}" var="key">         
                     <apex:variable var="count" value="{!1}"/>            
                     <apex:repeat id="contactDetails" value="{!mapDivision[key]}" var="att">
                         <tr>
                            <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!count==1}">
                                <td rowspan="{!(divisioncountMap[key])}" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!att.BD}"/>
                                </td>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                            <td><apex:outputText value="{!att.MB}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:outputText value="{!att.Name}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:outputText value="{!att.LE}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:outputText value="{!att.LD}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:outputText value="{!att.SG}"/></td>

                            <apex:variable var="count" value="{!count+1}"/>
                         </tr>
                     </apex:repeat>
                 </apex:repeat>                               
             </table>                     
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And this is my **UPD** controller:

```
public class FinancialProductsController {

//map to capture Division Name and List of Financial Products
public Map<String, List<FinProdWrapper>> mapDivision {get; set;} 
//map to capture Division Name and count of Financial Products which will be used to define rowspan.
public Map<String, Integer> divisionCountMap {get; set;}
//to capture list of Division Names
public List<String> divisionList {get; set;}

public FinancialProductsController(){
    mapDivision = new Map<String, List<FinProdWrapper>>();
    divisionCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
    divisionList = new List<String>();
}   

//prepare data to display in Visualforce.
public void getData(){
    List<Financial_Product__c> fd = [Select Business_Devision__c, Launch_Date__c, Name, Legal_Entities__c, Link_to_Confluence__c, Managed_by__c, Responsible_PM__c, Sales_Guru__c from Financial_Product__c];

    //grouped into division and prepare the map
    for(Financial_Product__c fdObj : fd){
        List<FinProdWrapper> fpWrapperList = new List<FinProdWrapper>();
        //verify map already contains same Division Name
        if(mapDivision.containsKey(fdObj.Business_Devision__c)){
            //retrieve the list of existing Financial Products
            fpWrapperList = mapDivision.get(fdObj.Business_Devision__c);
            //put the new Financial Product to the list
            fpWrapperList.add(new FinProdWrapper(fdObj));

            mapDivision.put(fdObj.Business_Devision__c, fpWrapperList);
            divisionCountMap.put(fdObj.Business_Devision__c, fpWrapperList.size());
        }                        
        else{
            //create a new map of Division Name
            fpWrapperList.add(new FinProdWrapper(fdObj));
            mapDivision.put(fdObj.Business_Devision__c, fpWrapperList);
            divisionCountMap.put(fdObj.Business_Devision__c, fpWrapperList.size());                
        }
    }
    //create a list of Division Names which will be helpful to iterate
    divisionList = new List<String>(mapDivision.keySet());
}

public Class FinProdWrapper {

    public FinProdWrapper(Financial_Product__c fn){
        this.Name = fn.Name;
        this.BD = fn.Business_Devision__c;
        this.LD = fn.Launch_Date__c.format();
        this.LE = fn.Legal_Entities__c;
        this.LTC = fn.Link_to_Confluence__c;
        this.MB = fn.Managed_by__c;
        this.RPM = fn.Responsible_PM__c;
        this.SG = fn.Sales_Guru__c;
    }

    public String Name {get; set;}
    public String BD {get; set;}
    public String LD {get; set;}
    public String LE {get; set;}
    public String LTC {get; set;}
    public String MB {get; set;}
    public String RPM {get; set;}
    public String SG {get; set;}        
}
```

}

As You recomend I try to create a wrapper class, and I get first column dinamically makes rowspan. But I don't get how to make the second column make rowspan as the first column.

Now I Have:

```
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
     |  B1 |  C1 |  D1 |
  A1 |  B1 |  C2 |  D2 |
     |  B1 |  C3 |  D3 |
```

But I need:

```
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
     |     |  C1 |  D1 |
  A1 |  B1 |  C2 |  D2 |
     |     |  C3 |  D3 |
```

Answer (score 4):

Examples such as this one [HTML  rowspan Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) reduce the number of `td` elements in the following rows (as `rowspan` is effectively saying use the content from the previous row).

So you need to modify your code to only output these `td` elements once in every 3 rows:

```
                 <td rowspan="3">{!fd.Business_Devision__c}</td>
                 <td rowspan="3">{!fd.Managed_by__c}</td>
```

<strike>That is probably going to take the introduction of an [apex:variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm) that you use to count.</strike> (Or you could introduce a [wrapper class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) where you pre-calculate a true/false for the output on the server-side.) Plus an [apex:outputPanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm) of `layout="none"` to do the conditional rendering of the pair of `td` elements.

Comment: I don't believe apex:variable works inside of apex:repeat tags for counting anymore (as it states in the second paragraph of the article you linked).

Comment: @gNerb Thanks - didn't know that. Will change the answer.

Comment: @KeithC Please look at my updated code

Comment: @Victor Best not to rely on the counter approach - see the warning that gNerb pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

```
A    |    B    |   C   |   D   |
     |         |   C1  |   D1  |
A1   |    B1   |   C2  |   D2  |
     |         |   C3  |   D3  |
```

> Based on the above given requirement, i had a similar code which shows Accounts and its related contacts in the same way and sharing it below if it may help you in any way.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="SampleController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form id="Form">
        <apex:messages />  
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <html>  
                <table class="list">
                    <tr class="headerRow">
                        <th>Account Id</th>
                        <th>Account Name</th>
                        <th>Account Created Date</th>
                        <th>Account Last Modified Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!AllFinProd}" var="fd">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!fd.Id}</td>
                            <td>{!fd.Name}</td>
                            <td>{!fd.CreatedDate}</td>
                            <td>{!fd.LastModifiedDate}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!fd.Contacts}" var="fd1">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"></td>
                                <td>{!fd1.FirstName}</td>
                                <td>{!fd1.LastName}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:repeat>

                </table>
            </html> 
        </apex:pageBlock>  
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

> Apex Class:

```
public class SampleController {
    public List<Account> getAllFinProd(){
        List<Account> fd = [SELECT Id,Name,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate, (SELECT FirstName, LastName from Contacts) from Account];
        return fd;
    }
}
```

I would also recommend using wrapper class to group the result based on the Business Division, suggested by Keith.

Comment: Please look at my updated code